# how can I use a plink to write to a text file

Tags: batch-file

I need to send numbers to a text file located on a remote windows machine , I'm using plink (putty command line-I have installed a ssh server on the windows machine) to establish the connection and it's successful but I'm having problems when I want to write numbers :

```
@echo off
cmd /c C:\Users\rob\Desktop\plink.exe -l user -pw password -ssh IP-remoteserver echo 10>> C:\Users\ser\Desktop\test.txt 

EXIT
```

C:\Users\ser\Desktop\test.txt--- the file  where I want to save the results.

Any ideas of how can I solve the problem? , not sure how can I use the echo function ,I just one to run this command on the remote server:

```
echo 10>> C:\Users\ser\Desktop\test.txt
```

But not sure how to add this part to the command where I run  plink.exe

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I didn't know how to use it so instead of writing remotely I just executed some other batch files located on the remote windows machine , something like this: batch to execute remote scripts on the server ----> batch located on the server that writes text on the text file, so I used 2 batches , I know is not the best solution but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to these instructions:

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

you can set up a saved session, then call plink with the session ID followed by your chosen command.